# How to create pseudo-binary phase diagrams using Thermo-Calc GUI?

Tags: calphad, thermo-calc, phase-diagram

How do you create pseudo-binary phase diagrams using Thermo-Calc? For instance how would I recreate the pseudo-binary phase diagrams shown below. I would prefer a method of doing this in the GUI (graphical mode), but if that's not possible I'll settle for a solution using the console mode.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thermo-Calc does not currently allow pseudo-binary phase diagrams using the graphical mode. The console mode has to be used to calculate them. For using the console mode, I would recommend looking at and following Example 17 in the [Thermo-Calc Console Mode Example Manual](https://thermocalc.com/wp-content/uploads/Documentation/Current_Static/thermo-calc-console-mode-example-macros.pdf).

To summarize, you have to (1) Define your components as the compounds in the pseudo-binary system, (2) Set the conditions in terms of these components, (3) Calculate the initial equilibrium, (4) Map the phase boundaries using the fraction of one component as the x-axis and temperature as the y-axis, and (5) Plot the phase diagram.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! It seems that the example requires suppressing the phases off the composition line. But how would I know what these are beforehand?

Comment: I would recommend first doing the calculation while ignoring the reject/restore steps if you are using a database other than that in the example, as those are for the example's particular system and database.

Answer (score 6):

## Alloy Theoretic Automated Toolkit (ATAT)

ATAT is a generic name that refers to a collection of alloy theory tools developped by [Axel van de Walle](http://alum.mit.edu/www/avdw), in collaboration with various [research groups](https://www.brown.edu/Departments/Engineering/Labs/avdw/atat/manual/node3.html) and with various sources of financial support.

#### sqs2tdb module

- Software tool for high-throughput CALPHAD (CALculation of PHAse Diagram) from first-principles,
- A. Walle, R. Sun, Q.-J. Hong, S. Kadkhodaei, *Software tools for high-throughput CALPHAD from first-principles data*. Calphad, **58**, 70-81, 2017. DOI: [10.1016/j.calphad.2017.05.005](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.calphad.2017.05.005)
- Download: [link](https://www.brown.edu/Departments/Engineering/Labs/avdw/atat/)

Comment: That seems interesting but do you know how to use Thermo-Calc to make pseudo-binaries?

Answer (score 1):

In Thermo-Calc 2022a and onwards it appears you can use the material-to-material calculator to extract phase information for a linear gradient between two compositions.